# TSLVersion error while trying to execute a translation task with IBM Watson

Tags: python, python-3.x, ibm-watson

I'm really super beginner with python and I'm trying to do an assignment from a Coursera course.  I need to write a simple code that connect through IBM Watson Translate and give results. So far, as per instructions, I`ve created a .env file which contains apikey and url of the Watson Service, then I've created another file to translate the text like this:

```
import json
from ibm_watson import LanguageTranslatorV3
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

apikey = os.environ['apikey']
url = os.environ['url']

# Setup service
authenticator = IAMAuthenticator(apikey)
lt = LanguageTranslatorV3(version='2018-05-01', authenticator=authenticator)
lt.set_service_url(url)

translation = lt.translate(text='We are sinking.', model_id='en-de').get_result()
translation
translation['translations'][0]['translation']
```

Also, prior to test the code, I 've run these commands to load the libraries per instructions:

```
python3 -m pip install python-dotenv
python3 -m pip install ibm_watson
python3 -m pip install Flask
```

The error I'm encountering is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):   File "translator.py", line 14, in <module>
        lt = LanguageTranslatorV3(version='2018-05-01', authenticator=authenticator)   File "/home/theia/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibm_watson/language_translator_v3.py", line 76, in __init__
        authenticator=authenticator)   File "/home/theia/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibm_cloud_sdk_core/base_service.py", line 97, in __init__
        self.http_adapter = SSLHTTPAdapter()   File "/home/theia/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibm_cloud_sdk_core/utils.py", line 35, in __init__
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/theia/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 130, in __init__
        self.init_poolmanager(pool_connections, pool_maxsize, block=pool_block)   File "/home/theia/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibm_cloud_sdk_core/utils.py", line 42, in init_poolmanager
        ssl_context.minimum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_2 AttributeError: module 'ssl' has no attribute 'TLSVersion'
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is because you need at least Python 3.7.

It's a nested dependency issue. Even though `ibm-watson` 6.1.0 has Python 3.5 as a dependency, it has a dependency on `ibm_cloud_sdk_core` 3.3.6.
If that is the version that you have downloaded then you might be ok, but I suspect that you have the latest 3.16.0. `ibm_cloud_sdk_core` has a dependency on Python 3.7 as a minimum.

I guess somewhere between 3.3.6 and 3.16.0 `ibm_cloud_sdk_core` introduced a breaking change.

You can check package versions with

```
pip freeze
```

or

```
pip list
```

An alternative would be to remove the version of `ibm-cloud-sdk-core` that you have and

```
pip install ibm-cloud-sdk-core==3.3.6
```

Either way you should raise an issue on https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk